# Treat nearly similar colour as same

Tags: php, mysql, database, colors, pattern-matching

I have a database containing colors in hex code in a column

**Example of colors :** `#EDAC13`, `#13C9ED`, `#BE13ED`.

If we take two colors like : `#ED9A13` and `#EB9710`.

These two colors are visually nearly same but different when we will query the table.

What I need is a process where I can select nearly same visual colors at the time of searching the database. I mean when I will search for `#ED9A13` then both `#ED9A13` and `#EB9710` will return. I am using `PHP` as my programming language.

> I know that storing RGB in three different columns is probably works but if I'm able to do this using hex code then It will be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if you do something like this in your db query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE color LIKE '#E_9_1_'
```

you will retrieve all colors where your code is like '#E(anycharacter)9(anycharacter)1(anycharacter)'...

'_' is wildcard for "one character"

'%' is wildcard for any characters (one or more)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably it will help me to certain extent but if the first letter changed or last letter changed I mean `E` or `1` then this process will fail. Can you please suggest me something better.

Comment: then why don't you use 'OR' operator (or union) and add your new condition LIKE '#_D_A_3' or something?

Comment: Actually I'm worried about the fine result, I don't know much about how hex code are made, I think I need to try your solution. I have to make sure during this the color must looks visually similar not entirely different.

Comment: it's like rgb but with letters/numbers associations... like : #RRGGBB with values from 0 to F (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F). #FF0000 is RED... & so on...

Comment: ohk! I got it, as FF is 255. I was checking your suggestion like : #3F5FFF and #3050F0 will be treated same, those are nearly similar but still bit different in eyes, for now it will save my day. I will have to improve it later on to make it perfect.